# Check and tidy up my JQuery function

Tags: jquery, show-hide, dropdown, contact-form-7

I'm new to JQuery but have managed to get it working the way I want. The problem is, it's a bit convoluted and could easily get out of hand if I add more options.

I am trying to show and hide divs based on a users dropdown selection. I've made a JSFiddle with where I am so far, but I think it could do with some streamlining.

```js
$(function() {
    $("select").change(function() {

        if ($(this).val() == "I have a query") {
            $("#cf-query").show("slow") && $("#cf-booking").hide("slow")
        } else if ($(this).val() == "I would like to book") {
            $("#cf-booking").show("slow") && $("#cf-query").hide("slow")

        } else {
            $(".cf-section").hide("slow");
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>What is the nature of your enquiry*:</h2>

<select id="cf-dd-nature">
    <option value="">--</option>
    <option value="I have a query">I have a query</option>
    <option value="I would like to book">I would like to Book</option>
</select>

<div class="cf-section" id="cf-query" style="display: none;">
    <h2>Query</h2>
    <p>First Name:</p>
    <p>Surname*:</p>
    <p>Email Address*:</p>
    <p>Telephone number*:</p>
</div>


<div class="cf-section" id="cf-booking" style="display: none;">
    <h2>Booking</h2>
    <p>First Name:</p>
    <p>Telephone number*:</p>
</div>
```

Could anyone give me any pointers? I'm willing to learn!
BTW, I'm using CF7 to build the form.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rchampniss/mdy7acwn/

Comment: Probably a better fit for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Only two things I'd suggest are to make your values simpler and not use $("#cf-query").show("slow") && $("#cf-booking").hide("slow").  Kill the && and end it with ; and write it on two lines.  Other than that, that's how you do it.

Comment: I'm going to be adding 5 more options to the dropdown, with 5 more contact divs. Will I need to hide each of them individually, or is there a way to say "if the div id is not the value selected, then hide it"?

Comment: Thanks @j08691, I've added my question to codereview. I dind't know that place existed! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution!

```js
    $(function() {
        $('#cf-dd-nature').change(function(){
            $('.cf-section').hide();
            $('#' + $(this).val()).show();
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script><h2>What is the nature of your enquiry*:</h2>

<select id="cf-dd-nature">
    <option value="">--</option>
    <option value="cf-query">I have a query</option>
    <option value="cf-booking">I would like to Book</option>
</select>

<div class="cf-section" id="cf-query" style="display: none;">
    <h2>Query</h2>
    <p>First Name:</p>
    <p>Surname*:</p>
    <p>Email Address*:</p>
    <p>Telephone number*:</p>
</div>


<div class="cf-section" id="cf-booking" style="display: none;">
    <h2>Booking</h2>
    <p>First Name:</p>
    <p>Telephone number*:</p>
</div>
```

Thanks for your help!